# How to send array to function as multiple arguments?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I have simple [test code](http://jsfiddle.net/MXNbK/):

```
function x(a, b) {
  alert(a);
  alert(b);
}

var c = [1,2];
x(c);
```

which send an argument `c` to function `x()` as one argument, assigned to `a` and `b` stays undefined :-/

How can I send an array as multiple arguments to a function, not as one array?

Comment: Why are you wrapping them in an array in the first place if you don't want an array? Just do `x(1,2)`

Comment: @TheZ I'm sure this is just an example

Comment: @JuanMendes Alright, then maybe `x(c[0],c[1])`? I guess I just don't understand what is required.

Comment: @TheZ Usually, because you don't know how many arguments you need to pass. That's why `Function.apply` exists

Comment: @JuanMendes Oh I see! I guess since the problem said nothing about variable sized arrays I didn't get that at all. Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

In your case (since you aren't using `this` in the function), you can simply pass `window` (or `this`) as the "this" argument:

```
x.apply(this, [1, 2]);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MXNbK/2/

Per your question about passing `null` as the "this" argument, see MDN's comment in the linked article on the "this" argument:

> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: **if the
>   method is a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will
>   be replaced with the global object**, and primitive values will be
>   boxed.

Comment: Would not be nicer to pass `null` as the first argument, as `this` has nothing related to such function(ality)...?

Comment: You could, but I believe `this` will still be `window` inside of the function.

Comment: @Ωmega Some browsers break when you pass null as this, even if not used

Comment: @JuanMendes - Ooops, really? I believe they should not, but okay... How about zero `0` - would that be acceptable for all browsers?

Comment: @Ωmega `0` wouldn't hurt, but why not just pass `this`? What is the advantage to passing anything else?

Comment: @Ωmega Maybe, I'm just explaining most people pass something because of that old bug, probably not even true with most browsers today except <IE6 or so.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker An advantage is making it clear that the function should not use the `this` keyword. But I'm with you, and passing `this` is what makes the most sense, so it maintains the same scope and makes it work even if `this` is added later

Answer (score 21):

Or, in browsers with ECMAScript 2015 (or with Babel transpiler), you can use the new spread operator:

```
x(...[1, 2])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10184249)

Comment: @dev-null This is a valid answer to the question. In ES6 [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) works very much like Function.apply.